# Thumbnails of shared Google docs give 404

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

When I request file info via the Google Drive API for a Google Docs file that can be viewed by anyoneWithLink I get a thumbnailLink that produces a 404 Error if you view it as an anonymous user. Is there a way to get a thumbnail for such shared files that can be viewed by anyone? For Drawings I found `https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/FILE_ID/image?w=WIDTH`, but I didn't find anything for the other file formats.

Answer (score -2):

Please use the `thumbnailLink` provided on the file resource. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: Even if the  permissions of the file let anonye (or `anyoneWithLink`) read the file, `thumbnailLink` does not work. It returns 404. I already saied so in my initial question.